# How to get time of question posting and question migration of a Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: support, migration, data-explorer, stackexchange-2.0

I want to retrieve time when a question is posted on a Stack Exchange website and time when its migrated (Basically time difference between question posting and migration).

Is there any way to get this using Stack Exchange data explorer?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how will you use this information?

Answer (score 2):

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202326/average-and-total-time-between-post-creation-and-migration) shows the time on average in days and hours for posts that are migrated.

```
select year([migration date]) as [year]
, avg(days) as [Avg. Days]
, avg(hours) as [Avg. Hours]
, count(*) as [Total]
from(
select ph.creationdate as [migration date]
     , p.creationdate as [Post date]
     , datediff(d, p.creationdate, ph.creationdate) as [days]
     , datediff(hh, p.creationdate, ph.creationdate) as [hours]
     ,posthistorytypeid
from posthistory ph 
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
where posthistorytypeid  in (35, 36)
) as dim
group by year([migration date])
order by year([migration date])
```

Result:

| year | Avg. | Days Avg. Hours | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | 1 | 24 | 167 |
| 2010 | 224 | 5383 | 804 |
| 2011 | 9 | 221 | 3428 |
| 2012 | 38 | 924 | 4188 |
| 2013 | 1 | 28 | 4127 |
| 2014 | 2 | 50 | 2311 |

You can find the [information for migrated posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233725/158100) in the PostHistory table for posthistorytypeid's 35 (away) or 36 (here)