# Missing migration-information in the StackExchange Data Dumps

Tags: support, data-dump

I downloaded the [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) for space.stackexchange.com and astronomy.stackexchange.com. As listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), the *PostHistoryTypeId* of the PostHistory.xml-Files should be "17" if a post was migrated. But none of the posts contains a "17", although for example [this Question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4352/why-did-nasa-intentionally-crash-the-lunar-atmosphere-and-dust-environment-explo) was migrated from astronomy.stackexchange.com to space.stackexchange.com. So why it isn't listed there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That list is old. They no longer use 17 for post migrations, they now use 35 and 36 for post migrations:

- **35** - Post Migrated Away
  This history event will only show up on the source site.
- **36** - Post Migrated Here
  This history event will only show up on the destination site.

For example, [this simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/query/edit/199623) shows eight questions which have been migrated away from Astronomy SE. Also keep in mind that posts *migrated away* may not always be present in the Data Explorer or data dump, as they eventually get deleted.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a new list or documentation of the structure of the data dump?

Comment: You can just query the PostHistoryTypes table and get them all: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199708